# SpringXD and Integration: Bridge, polleable &subscribable channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I'm reading the Spring Integration documentation to figure out how to implment a bridge with  [polleable and subscribable channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#polling-consumer) (which will be one of my SpringXD modules).

So [the documentation related to the bridge](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#bridge-namespace) says that basically, I should do something like:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

```
<channel id="pollable" />
<bridge input-channel="pollable" output-channel="subscribable">
    <poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="5000" />
</bridge>
<channel id="subscribable" />
```

Then I'm creating a SpringXD Stream like:

```
stream create source-customBridge-sink-testing --definition "kafka-source:kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=first-queue | custom-bridge | kafka-sink:kafka --topic=regular-queue" --deploy
```

But I'm getting:

> 2017-03-16T12:52:06-0300 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKStreamDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for stream 'source-customBridge-sink-testing': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sprin
>   gframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A poller should not be specified for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', since 'pollable' is a Subscrib.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are missing that the `pollable` must be declared as :

```
<channel id="pollable">
    <queue/>
</channel>
```